# how to close main thread from sub thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, vsto

I am working on VSTO. I had a long time consuming process so that i need to implement a stop button to stop the process. so that i create a UI form with stop button and show that UI form in a sub thread when my main process is called. Now i am trying to stop the main process from UI stop button but however i tried it closed all process and the document its self but i need to stop that process only
i have tried these for closing process but it not work properly

```
Enviorment.Exit(1);
process.Kill();
process.Close();
Close();
```

Comment: The question foesn't seem clear. Please try to clarify and add examples (maybe screenshots). Why are you using multiple threads for processing your data? What have you tried?

Comment: @xXliolauXx ok i write up again please review

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are calling a thread "process", but the question is about a sub thread, so I'll answer it for threads.

If you want to end your thread, make it regulary test a public bool, defined in your dialogbox class as "public volatile bool stopRequested = false;"
If the bool is set to true, just use the "return" keyword to stop the thread.

To abort the thread from your dialog box, just enter to the btn_Click event: "this.stopRequested = true;"

The thread will now realise the use wants it to stop, and it will jump to the line "return". Thread closed! \o/